# How to make a jquery infinite animation?

Tags: jquery, loops, jquery-animate

I'm trying to implement a jQuery function with an infinite loop to animate the body background with 3 colours. I cannot think of a nice and clean solution.
Something like this?

```
$(document).ready(function(){                
     $('body').animate({backgroundColor:'#ffcc00'}, 500, function(){
        $('body').animate({backgroundColor:'#eeeeee'}, 500, function(){
           $('body').animate({backgroundColor:'#3b5998'}, 500);
       });
   });
});
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can eliminate the nesting, but the solution is a little fatter:

```
var cols = "#ffcc00,#eeeeee,#3b5998".split(",")
var cPos = 0

$(document).ready(function() {
   swapC()
}    

function swapC() {
    $('body').animate({ backgroundColor:cols[cPos] }, 500)
    cPos++
    if (cPos == cols.length) {
        cPos = 0
    }
    window.setTimeout(function() { swapC() }, 500)
}
```

Comment: Do not use a timeout (which is unreliable), but a `animate()` callback function. You are risking race conditions.

Answer (score 22):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function animate() {
        $('body').animate({backgroundColor:'#ffcc00'}, 500, function(){
            $('body').animate({backgroundColor:'#eeeeee'}, 500, function(){
                $('body').animate({backgroundColor:'#3b5998'}, 500, function(){
                    animate();
                });
            });
        });
    }
    animate();
});
```

Comment: Won't this cause a stack overflow (no pun) after some time?

Comment: Good point, @AndyHin! Initially I thought the same, but the answer is: no.This is because .animate() adds the animation to the animation queue (together with the info about which function should be called when it's finished) and than the execution of the code immediately continues with the next statement.

Answer (score 9):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    colors = ['#FFB30C', '#58EC00', '#0087EC', '#EEEEEE', '#FF5A00' ]
    var i = 0;
    animate_loop = function() {
            $('body').animate({backgroundColor:colors[(i++)%colors.length]
            }, 500, function(){
                        animate_loop();
            });
    }
    animate_loop();
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/bHEVr/

Answer (score 7):

```
$(".elementsToAnimate").each(function setAnim(){
    $(this).
            animate({backgroundColor:'#ffcc00'},500).
            animate({backgroundColor:'#eeeeee'},500).
            animate({backgroundColor:'#3b5998'},500,setAnim);
});
```

Answer (score 5):

I would rather use an event-driven approach:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('body').on('color1', function () {
    $(this).animate({backgroundColor:'#ffcc00'}, 500, function(){
      $(this).trigger('color2');
    });
  });

  $('body').on('color2', function () {
    $(this).animate({backgroundColor:'#eeeeee'}, 500, function(){
      $(this).trigger('color3');
    });
  });

  $('body').on('color3', function () {
    $(this).animate({backgroundColor:'#3b5998'}, 500, function(){
      $(this).trigger('color1');
    });
  });

  // Kick-off the infinite loop by firing one of the events
  $('body').trigger('color2');
});
```

Watch this solution in action:

http://jsfiddle.net/perituswebdesign/f5qeo6db/1/

Answer (score 3):

Call the animate functions in the callback of animate().

See this example in the [jQuery forum](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/infinite-loop-with-jquery)

```
jQuery.fn.fadeInOut = function() {
        var newOpacity = this.is(":visible") ?  0 : 1;
        this.animate({ opacity: newOpacity }, function() {
                $(this).fadeInOut();
        });
        return this;
};

$("#mydiv").fadeInOut();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function blabla(){
 $('body').animate({backgroundColor:'#ffcc00'}, 500, function(){
        $('body').animate({backgroundColor:'#eeeeee'}, 500, function(){
           $('body').animate({backgroundColor:'#3b5998'}, 0,function (){
               setTimeout(blabla,500);
           });
       });
   });

}
```

**UNTESTED**

Answer (score 1):

Try this : http://jsfiddle.net/hBBbr/

```
$(document).ready(function(){

animate_loop = function animate_loop(){
        $( "#animated_banner" ).animate({
            opacity: 0.1, 

          }, 1000,function(){
               $( "#animated_banner").animate({ opacity: 1},1000)
                 animate_loop();
        } );    
}

animate_loop();  

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's years later but I think this could still be a problem for someone just like it was for me with jquery v1.10.2.
Anyway, after a few hours of trying to deal with it, I ended up using the following code for multiple layered backgrounds with [this plugin](http://keith-wood.name/backgroundpos.html):

```
// Self-calling functions for animation auto-repeat
var cssanimfx={
    bgb:function(o){
      o=$(o?o:this);
      o.css({backgroundPosition:'0px 0px'}).animate({backgroundPosition:"3000px -3000px"},500000,'linear',cssanimfx[o.attr('id')]);
    },
    bgm:function(o){o=$(o?o:this);o.css({backgroundPosition:'0px 0px'}).animate({backgroundPosition:"3000px -3000px"},250000,'linear',cssanimfx[o.attr('id')])},
    bgf:function(o){o=$(o?o:this);o.css({backgroundPosition:'0px 0px'}).animate({backgroundPosition:"3000px -3000px"},50000,'linear',cssanimfx[o.attr('id')])}
    // ...
}
// Initialize animation
for(id in cssanimfx)cssanimfx[id]('#'+id);
```

The naming scheme is as follows: I create nested **DIV**s and give them **ID**s in the HTML. In the JS part, the same **ID**s are used for keying the properties in the object containing all the self-calling-on-animation-finish functions. [Demo here.](http://jsfiddle.net/gbyrqbxj/)

Answer (score -1):

I highly recommend the **jQuery timing plugin (2KB)** ([GitHub](https://github.com/creativecouple/jquery-timing) & [Docs](http://creativecouple.github.com/jquery-timing/)).

It  provides easy-to-use infinite animations and much more. Have a look:

```
$(document).ready(function(){    

 $('body').animate({backgroundColor:'#ffcc00'}).wait(500)
          .animate({backgroundColor:'#eeeeee'}).wait(500)
          .animate({backgroundColor:'#3b5998'}).wait(500)
});
```

Comment: jQuery now have .delay() function, which make the same timing of (additional) .wait().

Comment: That's wrong. `.delay()` has been already integrated in version **1.4**. It  sets a timer to delay execution of subsequent items in the queue, but it does not provide infinite looping.