# Jquery to animate infinite times

Tags: jquery, html

I have a background image with hills, clouds and sun. My idea is to animate the background to keep on going from right to left.

Jquery:

```
$('#cloud-01').animate({backgroundPosition: '(-500px -80px)'}, 40000);
$('#cloud-02').animate({backgroundPosition: '(-625px -30px)'}, 40000);
$('#mountains-03').animate({backgroundPosition: '(-2500px 50px)'}, 40000);
$('#ground').animate({backgroundPosition: '(-5000px bottom)'}, 40000);
```

This is working correctly, but it is animating for 40s(Time given). After that it stops. What I need is to give the continuous moving effect.

I dont know how to repeat this animation once it is completed. Can anyone help me in this.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: similar question http://stackoverflow.com/q/4713477/1698732

Answer (score 2):

You can use javascript setInterval function for repeating your animation...

```
var animationRef=setInterval(40,function(){  
                                               /*call if animation if completed*/
                                               if ($(":animated").length === 0) {
                                                  animateBackground();
                                               }

                                          }
);

var animateBackground =function(){
   $('#cloud-01').animate({backgroundPosition: '(-500px -80px)'}, 40000);
   $('#cloud-02').animate({backgroundPosition: '(-625px -30px)'}, 40000);
   $('#mountains-03').animate({backgroundPosition: '(-2500px 50px)'}, 40000);
   $('#ground').animate({backgroundPosition: '(-5000px bottom)'}, 40000);
}
```