# How to continuously loop a block of Jquery using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, background

I do not code in JavaScript enough to make this code contentiously loop, or at least loop a bunch of times.

Here is the code, it fades the background of a div in and out now I want it to loop.

```
<script>
var timeInOut=2000

$(document).ready(function(){ 
     $("#background2").fadeIn(timeInOut,function(){
        $("#background3").fadeIn(timeInOut,function(){
        $("#background2").css("display","none");
        $("#background3").fadeOut(timeInOut);
        });
     });
 });
</script>
```

Thanks in advance,
Steve

Comment: setInterval(function(){},milliseconds);

Comment: exact duplicate of [How to make a jquery infinite animation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4713477/how-to-make-a-jquery-infinite-animation)

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    window.setInterval(function(){
         $("#background2").fadeIn(timeInOut,function(){
            $("#background3").fadeIn(timeInOut,function(){
            $("#background2").css("display","none");
            $("#background3").fadeOut(timeInOut);
            });
         });
     }, 1000); // 1000ms,  change to the interval you want.
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    window.setInterval(function(){
        $("#background2").fadeIn(timeInOut,function(){
            $("#background3").fadeIn(timeInOut,function(){
                $("#background2").css("display","none");
                $("#background3").fadeOut(timeInOut);
            });
        });
    }, timeInOut*3)
});
```

You could aswell not use timeout and do this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    loopFade()
});

function loopFade(){
    $("#background2").fadeIn(timeInOut,function(){
        $("#background3").fadeIn(timeInOut,function(){
            $("#background2").css("display","none");
            $("#background3").fadeOut(timeInOut, loopFade);
        });
    });
}
```

You might aswell want the `background2` to fade in while `background3` fade out. change the code for that :

Way #1 :

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    window.setInterval(function(){
        $("#background2").fadeIn(timeInOut,function(){
            $("#background3").fadeIn(timeInOut,function(){
                $("#background2").css("display","none");
                $("#background3").fadeOut(timeInOut);
            });
        });
    }, timeInOut*2)
});
```

Way #2 :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    loopFade()
});

function loopFade(){
    $("#background2").fadeIn(timeInOut,function(){
        $("#background3").fadeIn(timeInOut,function(){
            $("#background2").css("display","none");
            $("#background3").fadeOut(timeInOut);
            loopFade()
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  My syntax was just not quite right.  You forgot the 'n' in setInterval and I set the interval time to be timeInOut*3+500 which makes it run smoother. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

use `.setInterval` which calls the function after a specified time limit.

```
<script>
var timeInOut = 2000

$(document).ready(function () {

    var fadeFunc = function() {
        $("#background2").fadeIn(timeInOut, function () {
           $("#background3").fadeIn(timeInOut, function () {
               $("#background2").css("display", "none");
               $("#background3").fadeOut(timeInOut);
           });
        });
     });

    setInterval(fadeFunc,1000);
}); 
</script>
```