# How to loop a jquery animation for moving a div element

Tags: jquery, loops, jquery-animate

I have the following jquery script for moving two div elements one way, and then back again:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

$(document).ready(function(){
$('#left').animate({top:"0%"},15000);
$('#right').animate({top:"-126%"},15000);
$('#left').animate({top:"-127%"},15000);
$('#right').animate({top:"0%"},15000);
});
```

What I want to acheive is to have the above animation block repeat in an infinite loop. Can anyone suggest how I can achieve this please?

Comment: Have you tried these solutions?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4713477/how-to-make-a-jquery-infinite-animation

Answer (score 0):

with `setTimeOut()` you can repeat a code, the last value is the time after the code must be repeated.
You can use the `ClearTimeout()` function to clear any timer values previously stored.
try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setTimeout(function() {
         $('#left').animate({top:"0%"},15000);
         $('#right').animate({top:"-126%"},15000);
         $('#left').animate({top:"-127%"},15000);
         $('#right').animate({top:"0%"},15000); 
    }, 0);
});
```

Comment: Hi Alessandro, thanks for the answer however this does not seem to work, it still only runs the animation block the once?

Answer (score 0):

```
Here is the working example of the dynamic animation

$(document).ready(function(){
first();
function first(){   
 $(".left").animate({
     "left": "-=100px" 
 }, 3000, function(){
     $(".left").css("left", "100px");
 });

 $(".right").animate({
     "left": "0px"
  }, 3000, function(){
      second();
  });
};
function second(){
    $(".right").animate({
        "left": "-=100px"
    }, 3000, function(){
        $(".right").css("left", "100px");
    });

    $(".left").animate({
      "left": "0px"
    }, 3000, function(){
        first();
    });

  };
```

});

You can just put top on the palace of left in the css and js. 
http://jsfiddle.net/LPCE2/190/