# How to make CSS3 animation play on a loop

Tags: jquery, html, css, loops

I have this setup that I would like to play on repeat. I'm not great with jQuery so wondered if someone could show me how?

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jFIT/86KLb/4/)

```
$('.title1').fadeIn('fast', function() {
    $('div').addClass('animated pulse');
});

$('div').one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend    
animationend', function() {
    $('.title1').fadeOut(2000);
});
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4713477/how-to-make-a-jquery-infinite-animation

Comment: Have a look at `setInterval()`

Comment: Any reason why you can't use CSS instead of the fadeOut()? You can add it to the end of your CSS animation. If you post your CSS animation code, I'd be happy to show you what I mean.

Comment: Hey thanks for your response I'd be curious to see how you suggest I achieve this with css. My slider looks like this http://jsfiddle.net/akZ48/5/ and I'd want each title to fade in pulse and then fade out over each slide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/jFIT/86KLb/7/

Just wrap it all in a function and call it from the callback of fadeOut..

```
 doIt();

function doIt(){
  $('.title1').fadeIn('fast', function() {
      $('div').addClass('animated pulse');
  })
  $('div').one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend    animationend', function() {
    $('.title1').fadeOut(2000, function() {doIt();});
  });
};
```