# jQuery change background color with fade and return back to original with delay

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have the following function, that is supposed to change the background color with fade, then using delay return back to the original color. And endlessly repeat.

```
$(function () {
    $('div').animate({background-color: 'blue'}, 'slow', function () {
    $(this).delay(500).animate({background-color: 'red'}, 'slow');
 }); 
});
```

However it doesn't seem to work...
Any thoughts how to fix it?

Comment: is that it? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4713477/how-to-make-a-jquery-infinite-animation

Comment: Did you solve your problem by anychance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please do not forget to include **jquery-ui library**. Else it does not work

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.sample').click(function() {

    $(this).animate({
      backgroundColor: "green"
    }, 1000).delay(2000).queue(function() {
      $(this).animate({
        backgroundColor: "red"
      }, 1000).dequeue();
    });

  });

});
```

```css
.sample {
  font: normal 12px/18px 'Arial';
  color: #fff;
  background: red;
  padding: 20px;
  cursor: pointer
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="sample">
Click Me to see smooth background color transition and back to original background
</div>
</body>
```