# Endless loop jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I'm trying to make this fading background animation go on forever on the web page. How would I do this? Here is the code:

```
    $( document ).ready(function() {
    // Changing the background js code
    console.log('File Loaded! DELETE!!!');
    animate();
});
function animate() {
    window.setInterval(function(){    
    window.setTimeout(function(){
       $('.content').css('background-image','url(http://crondon.guko.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/confetti.jpg)');$('.content').css('transition','background 1s linear');$('.content').css('-webkit-transition','background 1s linear');$('.content').css('-moz-transition','background 1s linear');$('.content').css('-o-transition','background 1s linear');
    },3000);
        $('.content').css('background-image','url(http://crondon.guko.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/bride_groom_baronial_hall1.jpg)');$('.content').css('transition','background 1s linear');$('.content').css('-webkit-transition','background 1s linear');$('.content').css('-moz-transition','background 1s linear');$('.content').css('-o-transition','background 1s linear');
    },3000);
    animate();
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a jquery infinite animation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4713477/how-to-make-a-jquery-infinite-animation)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript/jQuery - Animated Background change with fade (infinite)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33599637/javascript-jquery-animated-background-change-with-fade-infinite)

Comment: (This has been asked again, hence closing as duplicate of the later question).

Answer (score 1):

You don't use setTimeouts inside a setInterval. I think you are looking for the functionality of setInterval. Take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval.

A basic example (which repeats every 1000ms or 1 second) would be:

```
setInterval(function() {
    // Code to repeat here
}, 1000);
```

Comment: With this code it doesn't work as once it changes the background once it doesn't do it again :/

Comment: @Callum, it sounds like that needs debugging then. You only need to call `setInterval()` once to set up a periodic event. Do you get any JS errors in your console? Can you set up a Fiddle for readers to look at?