# Javascript/jQuery - Animated Background change with fade (infinite)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am wanting to change the background of a div every 3 seconds. This needs to loop round so once the last background image shows it loops back to the first one and so on and so on. I'm having trouble doing so.

I made a post previous to this which was VERY vague and didn't get help.

```
    function animate() {  
    change1();
    change2();
    change3();
}
function change1() {  
       window.setInterval(function(){
        $('.content').css('background-image','url(http://crondon.guko.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/bride_groom_baronial_hall1.jpg)');$('.content').css('transition','background 1s linear');
    },3000);
    }
    function change2() {  
       window.setInterval(function(){
        $('.content').css('background-image','url(http://crondon.guko.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/confetti.jpg)');$('.content').css('transition','background 1s linear');
    },3000);
    }
    function change3() {  
       window.setInterval(function(){
        $('.content').css('background-image','url(x)');$('.content').css('transition','background 1s linear');
    },3000);
    }
    animate();
```

Comment: What trouble are you experiencing, exactly? If you can offer detail other than "it doesn't work", that would be ideal. For example, are your event functions called? Have you tried adding `console.log()` in each of them to see if they are being triggered? Have you independently checked that your transitions work OK?

Comment: What is happening is that it changes background once and after that it fades out then stays the same background.

Comment: OK. So, after the first trigger, are the events being triggered again? You need to see if the problem is that (a) the function attached to the event is not being called, or (b) that your transitions do not work if applied a second time. Add in a `console.log("Hello change 1");` as the first line in each function (changing the message as appropriate) to see what is happening.

Comment: Incidentally, you have three timers all operating on the same element(s), so they are likely to be "fighting" for which one is applied (they will all apply, and the last one to apply in each three-second period is probably the one that will appear to persist). Maybe comment out the last two and get one working at first?

Comment: Ah - do you wish to show these in sequence? If so, you need one timer, detect what image you are showing, and do a transition to the next one (or loop back to the first one).

Answer (score 1):

You totally overcomplicated this task. Just create an array with the URLs and a function that will set the slide URL, play the transition and set a variable that marks the next slide index. Then call this function with `setInterval()`.

```js
var currentIndex = 0;
var urls = [
    'http://crondon.guko.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/bride_groom_baronial_hall1.jpg',
    'http://crondon.guko.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/confetti.jpg',
    'http://media.caranddriver.com/images/media/51/dissected-lotus-based-infiniti-emerg-e-sports-car-concept-top-image-photo-451994-s-original.jpg'
];
var length = urls.length - 1;

function slide() {
    $('.content').css('background-image', 'url(' + urls[currentIndex] + ')');
    $('.content').css('transition', 'background 1s linear');
    currentIndex = (currentIndex < length) ? currentIndex + 1 : 0;
}

slide();

window.setInterval(slide, 3000);
```

```css
.content {
    height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content"></div>
```