# Loop FadeIn FadeOut Infinite

Tags: javascript, loops, fadein, fadeout

I need to repeat infinity this function does anyone can tell me a solution.

```
function AnimeRate(x, z, w){
    x.fadeIn(2000, function(){
        x.fadeOut(2000, function(){
            z.fadeIn(2000, function(){
                z.fadeOut(2000, function(){
                    w.fadeIn(2000);
                })
            })
        });
    });
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a jquery infinite animation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4713477/how-to-make-a-jquery-infinite-animation)

Comment: Nope, i have 3 separate divs which i need to display alternatively. I manage to display the first time but i cannot find a solution to come and start the function again. I am not javascript expert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.promise()`, `.then()`; move `AnimeRate` function inside of `.ready()` handler; call `.fadeOut(0)` on `w` element before recursively calling `AnimeRate`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  function AnimeRate() {
    return w.fadeOut(0).promise().then(function() {
      return x.fadeIn(2000).promise().then(function() {
        return x.fadeOut(2000).promise().then(function() {
          return z.fadeIn(2000).promise().then(function() {
            return z.fadeOut(2000).promise().then(function() {
              return w.fadeIn(2000).promise().then(function() {
                this.fadeOut(0).promise().then(AnimeRate)
              });
            })
          })
        })
      })
    })           
  }

  var x = $('.excellent');
  var z = $('.tresBon');
  var w = $('.bon');
  $(x, z, w).fadeOut(0);
  AnimeRate();
});
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/9rn45k43/5/

Comment: Not working, it come back to the first one but stopped and it did not hide the last one so i have got 2 divs showing

Comment: @Nicks _"Not working, it come back to the first one but stopped and it did not hide the last one so i have got 2 divs showing"_ Can you create stacksnippets, jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net to demonstrate? Note, `w` does not appear to fade out; you may need to begin `AnimeRate` with `w` fading out

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/9rn45k43/

Comment: @Nicks Included jQuery at jsfiddle by clicking "JAVASCRIPT" selecting a jQuery version; set all elements to `display:none` using `$(x, z, w).css("display", "none");` before inital call to `AnimeRate`;  `w.css("display", "none")` before animation calls within `AnimeRate` https://jsfiddle.net/9rn45k43/2/

Comment: Using `$(x, z, w).fadeOut(0)`; instead of `$(x, z, w).css("display", "none");` https://jsfiddle.net/9rn45k43/3/

Comment: The first loop works great and the loop continue, but the last part of the last div keep showing it won't hide

Comment: @Nicks Substituted `w.fadeOut(0)` for `w.css("display", "none")` https://jsfiddle.net/9rn45k43/4/

Comment: Still stop looping at the end ! And

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117004/discussion-between-nicks-and-guest271314).