# Making Infinite times animation in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Guys i want to make infinite times animation in jquery.
I have tried with following code but that animation is occurring only 1 times but i want continues and also i want to change the images on every step.

$(document).ready(function(){

```
            function  animation(){

                $("img").animate({

              'top':'440px'

           },'slow');

            setTimeout(function(){

                $("img").animate({

                   'top':'10px' 

                },'slow');

            },3000);



            }

            animation();
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a jquery infinite animation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4713477/how-to-make-a-jquery-infinite-animation)

Comment: Besides the duplicate I want to state something here - you are making a recursion calling your function `animation()` directly from itself. Recursions are a bit tricky and you should be very careful how are you using them. In your code there is nothing to stop the recursion so it will lead to a non-responding browser or the virtual machine will stop your code - whatever comes first. On the line above you call `setTimeout`. What is the reason you don't do it on the last line?

Comment: here is my fiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/vicsal/f03wmyrh/

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by calling the last parameter in an `.animate()` function, as the name of the function that the animation is in.

See example below:

```js
function animation() {
  $('#element')
    .animate({ //This moves the div down 90
      marginTop: 90
    }, 600)
    .animate({ //This moves the div back to the top
      marginTop: 0
    }, 600, animation); //the 'animation' parameter calls this function from the start
}

animation();
```

```css
#element {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="element"></div>
```

Let me know if you need any other help.

Answer (score 0):

I would use CSS for this

```css
.img {
  animation: bounce 5s infinite;
  position: absolute;
}

@keyframes bounce {
  0% {
    top: 10px;
  }
  50% {
    top: 200px;
  }
  100% {
    top: 10px;
  }
}
```

```html
<img class="img" src="http://placehold.it/100x100" />
```

Comment: but how to delay and change the image after every delay

Comment: 5 images - @Gerard