# How to loop an animation without a maximum call back error jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-animations, jquery-animate

I am trying to animate these two shapes up and down but only the first shape will animate and the other one won't and I get a "Maximum call stack exceeded error"

JavaScript function

```
function loopAnimation(shape, cssProperty, moveVal) {
            $(shape)
            .animate({[cssProperty]: "+=" + moveVal}, 1000)
            .animate({[cssProperty]: "-=" + moveVal}, 1000)
            loopAnimation(shape, cssProperty, moveVal);
        };
```

Function call

```
loopAnimation(cube, "top", "75%");
loopAnimation(triangle, "bottom", "75%");
```

Comment: This is because you have coded an infinite loop (`loopAnimation` calls `loopAnimation` calls `loopAnimation` forever).  You either need a way to code it in a non-blocking manner or, even better, to leverage CSS instead (if possible and pragmatic to your needs).

Comment: Try coding this using CSS keyframes/animation with infinite iteration-count rather than using jquery.

Comment: Looks like this is most likely a duplicate of the post [How to make a jquery infinite animation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4713477/how-to-make-a-jquery-infinite-animation)  FWIW, the solution there looks to be passing the looping/"recursive" call as a callback to the last `animate()`, which jQuery will internally manage to avoid a stack overflow.  Good luck, and happy coding!

Comment: Unfortunately without more context I can't say for certain.  If you feel the linked duplicate is not a duplicate, it would be helpful if you could update your post with additional information to illustrate the difference.  Most critically, a [mcve] that reproduces the issue would go a very long way in helping the community understand the issue you are facing.  (FWIW, this is information covered in [ask] and the [tour], if you are interested in gaining the most benefit from your time on SO.)

Comment: FWIW, I was able to [create a working example of your code using the callback-based approach:](https://jsfiddle.net/anied/eqxp574v/1/) https://jsfiddle.net/anied/eqxp574v/1/